# Maven Versions Plugin: versions:use-releases does nothing

Tags: java, maven, versions, versions-maven-plugin

I need change all snapshots dependency of my project before pass to release. I'm trying **versions:use-releases** from commandline *mvn versions:use-releases*, but it doesn't work for me. I'm using Nexus repository for releases and the releases versions are deployed correcly and with public access

```
<dependencyManagement>  
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.efx.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>efx-util</artifactId> 
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When I execute: mvn versions:use-releases, it does nothing.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building efx-clientesocket 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:use-releases (default-cli) @ efx-clientesocket ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building efx-clientesocket-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:use-releases (default-cli) @ efx-clientesocket-api ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building efx-clientesocket-impl 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:use-releases (default-cli) @ efx-clientesocket-impl ---
[INFO] Ignoring reactor dependency: com.efx.clientesocket:efx-clientesocket-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building efx-clientesocket-conf 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:use-releases (default-cli) @ efx-clientesocket-conf ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] efx-clientesocket .................................. SUCCESS [  1.539 s]
[INFO] efx-clientesocket-api .............................. SUCCESS [  0.031 s]
[INFO] efx-clientesocket-impl ............................. SUCCESS [  0.016 s]
[INFO] efx-clientesocket-conf ............................. SUCCESS [  0.015 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However versions:display-dependency-updates detect the corresponding release

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building efx-clientesocket-conf 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:display-dependency-updates (default-cli) @ efx-clientesocket-conf ---
[INFO] artifact junit:junit: checking for updates from nexus
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependency Management have newer versions:
[INFO]   com.efx.util:efx-util ................ 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> 1.0.0-RELEASE
[INFO]   junit:junit ............................................. 4.11 -> 4.12
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I'm also trying versions:use-last-releases as alternative and it goes OK. I'm using  -Dincludes= in this case to avoid updating no-snapshot versions. But, I would like to use **versions:use-releases** to assure updating only all-snapshot versions and cover versions in property at once

Maven version I'm using is 3.3.1 the plugin version is 2.2

Someone have any idea why does not working??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- versions:use-releases searches the pom for all -SNAPSHOT versions which have been released and replaces them with the corresponding release version.

```
com.efx.util:efx-util ................ 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> 1.0.0-RELEASE
```

This means `efx-util-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` should have a corresponding Release `efx-util-0.0.1-RELEASE` or `efx-util-0.0.1` (a released version of 0.0.1) otherwise it won't work. `1.0.0-RELEASE` is not a corresponding release

2- versions:use-latest-releases searches the pom for all non-SNAPSHOT versions which have been a newer release and replaces them with the latest release version.

In this case it's not restricted to the corresponding release of (0.0.1-SNAPSHOT). So the release may have a different version number (1.0.0-RELEASE).

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! this help me. Thanks a lot